# Python script corresponding to command

Tags: python, python-2.7, scripting

I am in the process of developing a script to change the password of an account through a Python script and all other modules except for the hash generation.

This is a working Python command to generate a hash against the password of choice with a random salt.

```
python -c "import crypt,random,string; print crypt.crypt(raw_input('clear-text password: '), '\$1\$' + ''.join([random.choice(string.ascii_letters + string.digits) for _ in range(16)]))"
```

What I need is to convert it to be a Python function. Can anyone please convert it as a Python module for me. I tried a lot but for some reason the script is not giving the encrypted hash back. Any help is appreciated, thank you.

Comment: Thanks for the response Martin. I just got it working now and I've pasted the correct code below. Sorry for the trouble :)

Answer (score 1):

Thanks for the quick response. I just figured the solution myself. I am posting it here so that anyone else might get it useful

```
import crypt
import random
import string
passwd = raw_input("Enter Email Password:")
saltvalue = '$1$' + ''.join([random.choice(string.ascii_letters + string.digits) for _ in range(16)])
print "%s" % saltvalue
print crypt.crypt(passwd, saltvalue)
```

Thakyou :)